How can I remove duplicate filenames from different directories in a list and use them once as xml tag text?
I have a file tree like :
2_Product
    2-1_CategoryName1_Product
        2-1-1_Name1_Product
            LLL_nomenclature1_product.zip
                LLL_nomenclature1_product (folder)
                    notice_nomenclature1.pdf
            LLL_nomenclature1_product_metadata.xml
            LLL_nomenclature2_product.zip
                LLL_nomenclature2_product (folder)
                    notice_nomenclature2.pdf
            LLL_nomenclature2_product_metadata.xml
            LLL_nomenclature3_product.zip
                LLL_nomenclature3_subproduct1 (folder)
                    notice_nomenclature3.pdf
                LLL_nomenclature3_subproduct2 (folder)
                    notice_nomenclature3.pdf
                LLL_nomenclature3_subproduct3 (folder)
                    notice_nomenclature3.pdf
            LLL_nomenclature3_product_metadata.xml
            ... etc
        2-1-2_Name2_Product
        2-1-3_ ...etc
    2-2_CategoryName2_Product
        2-2-1_ ...
        2-2-2_ ...
    ... etc
        

I have a script that searches my zipped folders for the 'notice_nomenclatureX.pdf' files and then adds a tag in the xml of the associated product with the name of the associated notice in it (here 'notice_nomenclature1.pdf' for example).
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import zipfile

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for folder_ext in files:
        if folder_ext[-4:] == '.zip' and folder_ext[:3] == 'LLL': 
            filePath3 = os.path.join(root, folder_ext)
            zip_folder = zipfile.ZipFile(filePath3)
            zipfile_paths = zip_folder.namelist() 
            for paths in zipfile_paths: 
                zipfiles = os.path.basename(paths)
                if zipfiles[-4:] == '.pdf' and zipfiles[:3] == 'not':
                    notice_name = zipfiles 
                    for prdt in files: 
                        if prdt[-4:] == '.xml' and prdt[:-13] == folder_ext[:-4] : 
                            filePath4 = os.path.join(root, prdt) 
                            xml_produit = ET.parse(filePath4) 
                            root_produit = xml_produit.getroot() 
                            notice_tag = ET.SubElement(root_produit, "notice_pdf") 
                            notice_tag.text = notice_name 
                            ET.indent(root_produit) 
                            xml_produit.write(filePath4, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml', short_empty_elements=False)

My script works well for 'nomenclature1' and 'nomenclature2' and gives this in my xml (what I want) :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http:...">
.
.
.
<notice_pdf>notice_nomenclature1.pdf</notice_pdf>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>

But for 'nomenclature3', I get (what I don't want) :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gmd="http:...">
.
.
.
<notice_pdf>notice_nomenclature3.pdf</notice_pdf>
<notice_pdf>notice_nomenclature3.pdf</notice_pdf>
<notice_pdf>notice_nomenclature3.pdf</notice_pdf>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>

How do I write in my script that when the 'zipfiles' variable contains the same notice name several times, it only transcribes one of them in the xml tag ?
I've tried using .sort() and sorted, to no avail.
And I tried this :
...
new_list = []
for paths in zipfile_paths:
    zipfiles = os.path.basename(paths)
    if zipfiles[-4:] == '.pdf' and zipfiles[:3] == 'not': 
        if zipfiles not in new_list:
            new_list.append(zipfiles)
            notice_name = new_list
... etc

"notice_nomenclature3.pdf" appears only once in "new_list" but when I run the script, it has a problem with the list format and it returns the following error :
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Would you know how I can achieve the desired result ?
Thank you.

Building a temp list with unique filenames and then iterating it could work: tempList = [] ... if filePath4 not in tempList: tempList.append(filePath4)

@LMC Indeed, iterating on it works. Thank you ! I've edited my post with the solution.

My mistake was to use 'tempList' directly as text of the tag.
By adding a 'for' statement that searches the 'tempList', I get the desired result.
Below is my modified code :
    for folder_ext in files:
        if folder_ext[-4:] == '.zip' and folder_ext[:3] == 'LLL': 
            filePath3 = os.path.join(root, folder_ext)
            zip_folder = zipfile.ZipFile(filePath3)
            zipfile_paths = zip_folder.namelist() 
            tempList = []
            for paths in zipfile_paths: 
                zipfiles = os.path.basename(paths)
                if zipfiles[-4:] == '.pdf' and zipfiles[:3] == 'not':
                    if zipfiles not in tempList:
                        tempList.append(zipfiles) 
                        for prdt in files: 
                            if prdt[-4:] == '.xml' and prdt[:-13] == folder_ext[:-4] : 
                                filePath4 = os.path.join(root, prdt) 
                                xml_produit = ET.parse(filePath4) 
                                root_produit = xml_produit.getroot() 
                                notice_tag = ET.SubElement(root_produit, "notice_pdf") 
                                for notice_name in tempList :
                                    notice_tag.text = notice_name 
                                    ET.indent(root_produit) 
                                    xml_produit.write(filePath4, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml', short_empty_elements=False)```


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
